# Logout or signout user is not working with window service C#

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I am facing issue with logout/Signout user trough the window service. I have tried 4 different ways which is mentioned below but its not working. It is working fine when I am debugging the service but when I am creating a setup of service and running it then its not working.

1st way

```
    ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
```

2nd way

```
     if (!WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 
                                     WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false))
                                    throw new Win32Exception();
```

3rd way

```
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    info.FileName = "shutdown";
                    info.Arguments = "-l";
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    Process p = Process.Start(info);
                    p.WaitForExit();
```

4th way

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-l");
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? Any if this is a windows service, why does the question have `asp.net` and `web-services` tags?

Comment: Not sure, but when you are debugging the service, it is running under your account and will logout you. When you install the service, it is running under a different account (LocalSystem?). I think that this account can't logout.

Comment: @ Ben Its not working with Local System also. I am creating a setup of the same service code and installing it on the local system but its not working. But in the case of debugging the same code its working. I don't know whats happening.